# Specificity/Sensitivity vs cut-off points using pROC package

Tags: plot, logistic-regression, metrics, roc, proc-r-package

I need to plot the following graph so I can choose the optimal threshold for a logistic regression model.

[image: Plot of Sensitivity and Specificity as a function of the Cutoff]

However I can't use the packages (epi and roc) which are used in many of the research I have done. I do have the package pROC. Is there anyway to plot the graph using this package. Also how else could I choose the optimal threshold? How does it work using only the ROC curve?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the pROC package, the first step is to extract the coordinates of the curve. For instance:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
myroc <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$ndka)
mycoords <- coords(myroc, "all")
```

Once you have that you can plot anything you like. This should be somewhat close to your example.

```
plot(mycoords["threshold",], mycoords["specificity",], type="l", 
     col="red", xlab="Cutoff", ylab="Performance")
lines(mycoords["threshold",], mycoords["sensitivity",], type="l", 
      col="blue")
legend(100, 0.4, c("Specificity", "Sensitivity"), 
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1)
```

Choosing the "optimal" cutpoint is as difficult as defining what is optimal in the first place. It highly depends on the context and your application.
A common shortcut is to use the Youden index, which is simply the point with the cutoff with max(specificity + sensitivity). Again with pROC:

```
best.coords <- coords(myroc, "best", best.method="youden")
abline(v=best.coords["threshold"], lty=2, col="grey")
abline(h=best.coords["specificity"], lty=2, col="red")
abline(h=best.coords["sensitivity"], lty=2, col="blue")
```

With pROC you can change the criteria for the "best" threshold. See the [?coords](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/coords) help page and the `best.method` and `best.weights` arguments for quick ways to tune it. You may want to look at the [OptimalCutpoints package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v061i08) for more advanced ways to select your own optimum.

The output plot should look something like this:

[image]